# Gradle build shows error: Unsupported node 'item'

Tags: android

[image]

My project does not gradle it shows:

> Error:Execution failed for
>   task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>    D:\Android\MatarealDesigen\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml: Error: Unsupported node 'item'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Please go to `res/values/styles.xml` and find the error there. One of the tags called "item" is probably in the wrong place (it should be highlighted in red) :-)

Comment: i took fragment_home fragment and then R is colored red as image shown.

Comment: Did you go to styles.xml?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the name of one of the attributes was misspelled:

> tye="layout"

instead of

> type="layout"

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a different error message, when you did that.